# How to supply power outside under soffit

Tags: gfci

See photo in post. I want to install a camera and flood light under the roof soffit. The soffit area in the attic is very difficult to access. Also I want to be able to replace the camera easily since they can go bad. I want to be able to plug a new one in easily. I am getting power from a 15 amp junction box in the attic. In the attic I am using 14/2 with ground NM Romex grey color. The package says it’s for outdoor or indoor use, the grey wrapper is much stronger than the white wrapper.

I attached a male electric plug to one end of the Romex so it plugs into the outlet in the attic. I will run the Romex from the electrical box along the roof rafter trusses then go through the outside wall and vinyl siding near the top gable vent which is about 20 feet up from the ground. I will use Moldable Silicone Putty or Duct Seal Compound to seal the wire and hole.

My plan was to run the Romex down the drip edge of the roof line then under the soffit into a GFCI Outlet 15 Amp that is attached to the soffit the GFCI will be facing down . My question is do I need to follow the code. Do I need to protect the Romex once it comes out of the house and run it inside PVC Conduit? Can Romex go inside rigid PVC Conduit or should I use individual THWN wire? Do I have to use rigid PVC or can I use Liquidtight Flexible Non-Metallic PVC Conduit Cable?

[image: Roof soffit]
[image]

Comment: instead of running the NB cable outside, drill a hole into the soffit  where you want to install the outlet. From the outside push all your cable  into the hole except for 12".  Then from in the attic hook on to the cable with a long pole/hook and pull the cable toward you. Then make the appropriate connections in you junction box.

Comment: @jack I agree with you but there may not be enough space even drilling from the underside and poking the cable through, with a low pitch and not much overhang I have found homes that did not have enough room to mount a shallow box except surface mount and the owner did not want that or conduit but chose conduit to a surface box in the same location where the UF is located in this photo, (UF not nmb by description) I am wondering if op did the work and someone told him it was not legal and now looking for advice.+

Comment: Jack, I see what your saying. Instead of running wire outside. I can run the wire from the attic to the soffit then directly into the back of the GFCI Outlet on the soffit. So that no part of the Romex it exposed outside.

Comment: My photo is Photoshopped and is not real. I have not actually done the work yet.

Comment: I was able to poke a wire from the outside through a hole in the soffit and found it in the attic. I did not think about placing GFCI Outlet on the soffit hole so that the wire cable wasn't exposed.

Comment: @paulcap1 you will need a box to house the outlet. But make sure your area will allow a permanent mounted light to be cord connected with a receptacle.

Comment: After looking again, as this is an elevated position I would have it on a GFCI breaker.  If you do go with twin duplex receptacles only 1 GFCI would be needed and it needs to be WR (weather rated) feed the second receptacle from the load terminals of the GFCI and they will all be protected. An extreme duty box cover is kind of a waste in this location and may not be required. Under soffits are already protected and not required in any of the areas I have worked in the last 10 years.

Comment: Why are you trying to put a plug on the attic end of this UF run instead of just hardwiring it in at the receptacle box?

Comment: @Jack. I added a new photo to the post. I will use a weather tight box mounted to the soffit and the UF cable will not be exposed. For the laws regarding plugging devices in like cameras, flood light or Christmas lights. I can always unplug and remove the device if I need to sell my house so it can pass inspection. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gray Romex is normally type UF (underground feeder) look at the info printed on it it should say UV resistant, if it is it would be legal to attach it as you have in the photo if that low point is above 8’ (but look like a hack job) the part that would not be legal or “code compliant” would be plugging it in. There should be a splice inside the box that has the outlet, if the box fill is two large or two many wires for that sized box a larger box or box extension will be needed to make the splice.

Comment: Ed, I also read that if your above 8ft. It is fine to run Gray UF Romex outside. When you say plugging it in. Do you mean the plugging in of the security camera into the GFCI Outlet that is on the soffit? There is a junction box in the attic and that is where the wire is spliced in.

Comment: Ed I changed my original post. I am getting power from a 15 amp junction box in the attic and not a 15 amp outlet in the attic.

Comment: absolutely if plugged inside the dwelling it would violate code , the outside light may violate code , if mounted to the building depending on the jurisdiction, my current location if the receptacle is in a location that is not a wet location (soffit , outside covered porch or open barn)  it would be allowed. 2 county’s to the north if it is outside and hard mounted it cannot be cord connected. I run into this with pole barns mostly hang the fixture on chains and a plug connection above the fixture is ok, hard mount and now it is not compliant. So it comes down to the inspectors call.

Comment: @Ed Beal - When you say "There should be a splice inside the box that has the outlet,...", you're talking about the box inside the attic right?

Comment: Splice or pigtail in the box in the attic. I just try to keep folks from using backstabs , they have been the leading cause of electrical failures that I have seen.